Bringing gifted wedge tail eagle feather back from Australia via Canada to the US
My son was gifted a wedge tail feather by the staff of a wildlife sanctuary in Queensland, Australia when it fell off during a raptor demonstration. Is it legal to keep this feather and bring it back to the US from Australia? We will have to pass through Canadian customs on our way back. What type of issues may we encounter when going through customs?

Did your son get any paperwork at all concerning the provenance of the feather? It would make his life much easier if so. Perhaps contact the sanctuary and ask them for a letter stating that it was a gift from them as a shed feather from a Wedge-tail. That would help proving to both Canadian and US customs exactly the type of feather and how it was obtained.

I once brought back a conch shell, which is on the CITES list of things you can't bring back, but there is an exception if you actually picked it off the seafloor yourself (rather than buying it) and I declared it and explained and it was allowed in.
Checking https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/publications/dm-md/d19/d19-7-1-eng.html, a Memorandum from Canadian Border Services Agency, I see:

Travellers who transport eagle parts and feathers as personal accompanied baggage for religious or ceremonial purposes are exempted from CITES permit requirements for importation into Canada. Presentation of valid identification verifying their status as a recognized "Aboriginal" or "Status Indian" or as being part of the "Aboriginal Community" is required at the time of importation. This exemption is granted as part of an international agreement between the U.S. and Canada specifically for status aboriginals transporting eagle parts and feathers for religious and ceremonial purposes between the two nations.

So unless your son has status, you should not say you want to bring this feather for religious or ceremony reasons. It may be ok under this clause:

Tourist Souvenirs


A CITES export permit (from the country visited) is not required for residents of Canada returning from a trip outside the country with souvenirs of CITES Appendix II
or III species, if imported in their accompanying baggage or as part of their clothing or accessories. However, tourists are still advised to check with the CITES authority of the exporting country, which may have its own requirements with respect to what wild animals and plants may or may not be taken out of the country by tourists.

Unfortunately their link to CITES II is broken. I do see a list of stuff that can never be exempted, and eagle feathers aren't on that list, so Canada is probably not going to have a problem with the feather.
That said, Canada will not let you take it into the US. https://www.canada.ca/en/environment-climate-change/services/convention-international-trade-endangered-species/wild-animal-plant-protection-act/travelling-eagle-items-guidelines-aboriginal.html says:

If you are not a member of a recognized tribe under the U.S. Bureau of Indian Affairs or a Status Indian under Canada's Indian Act you will not be allowed to possess or transport items containing eagle feathers or eagle parts into, within, or out of the United States.

The details that follow refer only to bald and golden eagles. You might want to call CBSA to ask if a wedge tail eagle feather is ok. (And think about how you can prove to a customs officer that this is such a feather.)

The list of species protected under CITES is available here;  the wedge-tailed eagle (Aquila audax) is not listed there.  Concerning the protections for bald & golden eagles, and the exemptions for First Nations groups, those probably refer to specific exemptions to the enabling acts for the Migratory Birds Treaty of 1918.  This treaty only applies to species native to the United States & Canada, so it wouldn't apply to the wedge-tailed eagle either.

How does one determine what type of large raptor a feather is from? A customs inspector is unlikely to assume it is anything but a prohibited bird. (See my comment on the question.)

I agree. A picture of the child holding the feather with a wedge tailed eagle nearby or the sign for the exhibit or whatnot might help, but I think proving what kind of feather it is will be a real issue.
